# XML that used to validate doesn't

Tags: xml, validation, schema

I used XML on a program about 3 years ago, simple stuff. I need now for another task and I just pulled up the old files and made some insignificant changes and now my document doesn't validate. I'm puzzled, it looks pretty simple. Here's my schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

   <xs:complexType name="Task_t">
       <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="ShortTitle" type="xs:string"/>
           <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string"/>
           <xs:element name="Content" type="xs:string"/> 
       </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>

   <xs:element name="History" type="History_t"/>

   <xs:complexType name="History_t">
       <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="Task" type="Task_t"></xs:element>
       </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

and here's my document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<History xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:/Users/pcezanne/Documents/work/stackoverflow/TestSchema.xsd">
   <Task>
       <ShortTitle>Market Needs</ShortTitle>
       <Title>Market Needs Sample Content</Title>
       <Content>MarketNeeds.html</Content>
   </Task>
   <Task>
       <ShortTitle>The Big Concept Answers Market Needs</ShortTitle>
       <Title>Market Needs Sample Content</Title>
       <Content>BigConcept.html</Content>
   </Task>
   <Task>
       <ShortTitle>Solutions</ShortTitle>
       <Title>Market Needs Sample Content</Title>
       <Content>Solutions.html</Content>
   </Task>
   <Task>
       <ShortTitle>Why Us?</ShortTitle>
       <Title>Market Needs Sample Content</Title>
       <Content>WhyUs.html</Content>
   </Task>
   <Task>
       <ShortTitle>Next Steps</ShortTitle>
       <Title>Market Needs Sample Content</Title>
       <Content>Next Steps.html</Content>
   </Task>
</History>
```

Oxygen fails to validate this, complaining about the 2nd  "No child element is expected at this point." I thought that thats what  was for!

I do know that when I wrote this 3 years ago it was my first schema, so maybe I'm doing something stupid. I don't mind being told that. :- ) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I should ask is do the original files work without the modifications? It's usually the changes that *I think* are insignificant that cause me the most unexpected problems!

I can't answer what you have changed to break the validation but I can see that the [`<xs:sequence>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#element-sequence) is missing `maxOccurs="unbounded"`. The default for `maxOccurs` is 1 so the schema is only expecting 1 Task.

The following type allows multiple `Task` elements in my quick test locally.

```
<xs:complexType name="History_t">
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Task" type="Task_t"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: sadly, I can't test the original code anymore.. but yes, the maxOccurs tag sounds about right!